# Any other words that use “dis-” as an amplifying prefix?

Tags: etymology, prefixes

I remember hearing once about the etymology of *disgruntled*, probably based around a joke about how people can not be *gruntled*. The explanation given was that there was never a word *gruntled*, rather the *dis‑*  in *disgruntled* is actually a usage of the old prefix where it acts like an amplifier.

Firstly, is this true?

Secondly, are there any other words that use this prefix in this way?

Comment: Can people be "tracted" or "torted"?

Comment: Somewhat related: "Kempt" by Tripod: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IngvNUaWvck .

Comment: I'd like to point out that, although there was no _gruntled_ there was a _gruntle_. See [this link](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=gruntle&searchmode=none).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Oxford American Dictionaries, the prefix *dis‑*  can also express

> completeness or intensification of an unpleasant or unattractive action

This definition cites the examples *discombobulate* and *disgruntled*.

Other interesting examples of words having the prefix in this particular sense are *disaster*, *distend*, and *disport*.

As an addendum, *dis‑*  obviously has other implications, for example *reversal, separation, removal, negation,* etc., but I’m focusing on the meaning specified by the author of this question.

Comment: Discombobulate is a wholly contrived word. To the extent we can break into a prefix and root, dis- here is clearly negates combobulate (see: recombobulate - to put back in order). Disaster is "bad star," to distend is "apart" + "pull" (literally, rather than figurative but some sense) and disport is "away" + "carry."

The only one that this "completeness" sense is disgruntled, and I have not be able to find a sensible origin for that sense of dis-.

Answer (score 0):

The only one I can think of is *disheveled*. Or perhaps *disaster*?

Comment: Let me take some of that back. Apparently the "sheveled" in "disheveled" comes from a French word for "hair." Sorry, I should have done my research!

Comment: And, according to this link (http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/why-isnt-gruntled-a-word.aspx) "grunetlen" was a Middle English word, and it was indeed possible to be "gruntled." Apparently, not anymore!

Answer (score 0):

How about *discordant*? I don't think anything is ever *cordant*.

Comment: Can anything be "membered" or "gusted", too?

Comment: The thing is not all the roots of words beginning with the prefix "dis-" will make sense on their own. "dis-" denotes several things, some of which are expulsion, removal and separation. "dis-" also negates. Thus, in "discordant", which means "lack of harmony", "dis-" negates or denotes a lack. In "dismember", "dis-" denotes separation. In "disgust", "dis-" reverses the taste, as it were. The OP's question deals with "dis-" as specific to denoting "amplification" or "intensification", especially of something unpleasant.

Comment: As an example, "distend" means "to swell". Another is "disport", which is an old word for "partying too hard"!

Comment: I was jesting of course; more often than not, a lot of prefixes and suffixes assume duties different from the conventional.

Comment: @J. M.: I should be more relaxed, so I can enjoy the humor in life! Thanks for clarifying. I'm slow, sometimes.

Comment: A 'discord' would relate to 'chord'. In music, a chord is (traditionally) consonant. A discord would be dissonant. Of course, our sense of harmony has widened since then, and we use many dissonant chords in modern music.

Comment: And people are born 'membered' (usually), so we can only dis-member them. I guess someone who makes prosthetic limbs could 'member' someone.